# Failed to setAutoCommit to true - Weblogic 12 - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, weblogic

We have an application using a Weblogic pooled non-XA SQL Server JDBC driver. Here is the flow of what is causing the issue.

Get connection from datasource.

Set auto commit to false.

Create CallableStatement.

Set parameters.

Call executeUpdate.

- Inside stored proc call, the database raises an error with SET XACT_ABORT as ON

Application sees error code in out param of CallableStatement.

Closes CallableStatement

Calls rollback on the connection.

Exception is thrown:

> 2013-Oct-17 16:45:20.500
>   EDT||XXXXXXX|asyncDelivery9|XXX|XXX|XXXX-a3436e48-1672-4a26-88c0-50b9954f6a42|ERROR|XXXXX|rollBack|The
>   server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:4200000012.
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The server failed to
>   resume the transaction. Desc:4200000012.
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
>   ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
>   ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)
>   ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:39)
>   ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$1ConnectionCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1756)
>   ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
>   ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
>   ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectionCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1761)
>   ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.rollback(SQLServerConnection.java:1964)
>   ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
>           at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection_com_microsoft_sqlserver_jdbc_SQLServerConnection.rollback(Unknown
>   Source) ~[wlfullclient.jar:12.1.1.0]

Connection is closed.

Then the next time the application attempts to get a connection from the data source, the following error is thrown:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to setAutoCommit to true for pool connection: First we got The server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:4200000012., then we got The server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:4200000012.
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection.init(PoolConnection.java:70) ~[wlfullclient.jar:12.1.1.0]
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getPoolConnectionObj(RmiDataSource.java:639) ~[wlfullclient.jar:12.1.1.0]
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getPoolConnection(RmiDataSource.java:478) ~[wlfullclient.jar:12.1.1.0]
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnectionInternal(RmiDataSource.java:558) ~[wlfullclient.jar:12.1.1.0]
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:518) ~[wlfullclient.jar:12.1.1.0]
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:511) ~[wlfullclient.jar:12.1.1.0]
```

In the Weblogic log, the following is logged:

```
<Oct 15, 2013 3:07:50 PM EDT> <Warning> <JDBC> <BEA-001153> <Forcibly releasing inactive/harvested connection "weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection_com_microsoft_sqlserver_jdbc_SQLServerConnection@238607" back into the data source connec
tion pool "MASTERDB", currently reserved by: reclaimed because of init failure before user access. Not because of inactivity..>
```

It seems to me that the transaction on the connection was never ended.  But a rollback was called which I would have thought would end the transaction.  And now the next time Weblogic attempts to return the connection, it errors when initializing it.  Any ideas as to what the issue is?  We are not explicitly setting auto commit back to true at the end, could that be the issue?

Comment: Try adding `defaultAutoCommit=false` in the properties for the connection pool to see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Found this suggestion for same similar problem [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/913747?tstart=0).

"Make sure you have the datasource/pool configured to test-on-reserve, and seconds-to-trust = 0."

This should solve the issue of eliminating those "bad" connections from pool before returning to application.